# figure out ld command arguments from xcode run script build phase

Tags: xcode, xcodebuild, xctool

How can I determine what will be the arguments of the ld command in the build process from inside a script running as "run script build phase"?

I was looking at `xcodebuild -dry-run` as an option, but then I need to understand what should be the arguments I supply it.

Any idea for a robust solution?

**EDIT**:

It seems that xcodebuild doesn't support LD and LDPLUSPLUS when the project includes swift source code. So the solution that @fpotter offered doesn't work on project with swift.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5):

Xcode doesn't expose a nice way to do this.  In a *Run Script* build phase, all you have to work with are the Xcode build settings provided to you in the environment.

If you really need the entire argument list to `ld`, there's a hack you can use.  With the `LD` and `LDPLUSPLUS` build settings, you can make Xcode call a script of your own instead of the real `ld`.  From that script, you could capture the args, call through to the real linker, and then do whatever post processing you like there rather than in a Run Script build phase.

Here's how you could do that:

**Create an .xcconfig for your target.**

It should look like this:

```
LD = $(SRCROOT)/ld-wrapper/clang
LDPLUSPLUS = $(SRCROOT)/ld-wrapper/clang++
```

SRCROOT points to your project's directory.  The LDPLUSPLUS line is only required if your app has C++ or ObjC++ code.  If you don't want to create an xcconfig, you can also add these as User-Defined build settings via the Xcode UI.

**Create wrapper scripts for Xcode to call.**

Install a script like this at `<your project root>/ld-wrapper/wrapper.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -o errexit

# Choose which clang to run (clang or clang++) depending on how we're invoked.
# If we're invoked via the 'clang' link, we'll run 'clang'.  If we're invoked
# via the 'clang++' link, we'll run 'clang++'.
CLANG_PATH="$DEVELOPER_DIR"/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/$(basename "$0")

"$CLANG_PATH" "$@"

echo "clang args: $@"
echo "do any post processing here."
```

Create symlinks for the wrapper script for clang and clang++:

```
cd <project root>/ld-wrapper
ln -s wrapper.sh clang
ln -s wrapper.sh clang++
```

That's it.  It's ugly, but it works.

Comment: Thanks @fpotter, glad to be the first one you answer in SO. I think that the LD variable approach is interesting. Why can't I parse the result of `xcodebuild -dry-run`?

Comment: You certainly could parse the output of `dry-run`.  But, calling xcodebuild with `dry-run` from within a Run Script would be slow.  Even if only doing a dry-run, xcodebuild spends a lot of time opening your projects and preparing to build.  On really large projects, it could take more than a minute just to do a dry-run.

Comment: do you have any clue why xcode disregards LD and LDPLUSPLUS variable when the project contains swift code?